# I get a 405 Method not allowed by Postman if I send my server a get request with params

Tags: java, http, server, glassfish

**If I send my server an GET-request with params, I'm getting a** `405 - Method not allowed`.

```
 package pkgService;

 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
 import pkgData.pkgEmployee.User;
 import pkgServer.pkgUser.UserManagement;

 import javax.ws.rs.*;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/user")
public class UserRouter {

     private UserManagement userManagement;
     private ObjectMapper objMap;

     public UserRouter() {
         this.userManagement = new UserManagement();
         objMap = new ObjectMapper();

         //TODO delete test data
         userManagement.addUser(new User(1,"lukad", "luki"));
         userManagement.addUser(new User(2,"meli", "malal"));
     }

     @GET
     @Path("{userId}")
     public Response getBook(@PathParam("userId") String id) {
         Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
         try {
             response.entity(objMap.writeValueAsString(userManagement.getUser(id)));
         } catch (Exception e) {
             response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
             response.entity("[ERROR] " + e.getMessage());
         }
         return response.build();
     } }
```

I expect to get the user with the id 1 (lukad,luki), but I received a 405.

My postman request Url:
    http://localhost:8080/Server_war_exploded/user?userId=1

**Did I forget something in the code ?**

Comment: Have you debugged your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change function as by adding '/' before user id

```
@GET
@Path("/{userId}")
     public Response getBook(@PathParam("userId") String id) {
}
```

Also if you are using PathParam then you need  to change url also as

```
 http://localhost:8080/Server_war_exploded/user/1
```

where 1 is user id

But if you want to use

```
 http://localhost:8080/Server_war_exploded/user?userId=1
```

Then you need to use QueryParams and change your code as follow

```
 @GET
 public Response getBook(@QueryParam("userId") String id) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Path("{userId}")`

It is missing regex. How can it know what is now the users id and what is just the next step in path?

It should be something like this (if your id is really a string...):
`@Path("{userId:\\w+}")`

Comment: (yes my id is a string. right now its just a testid) 
You have a point but my Server now responds with 404 :/.
The "main problem" is that i "copy" from another programm which has the same code but it works there.

Comment: If you are using this uri to get your resource  (http://localhost:8080/Server_war_exploded/user?userId=1) then it will not work. `?userId` is a Query Param, not a PathParam
For query params you need something like this as your method parameter `@QueryParam("userId") String userId`
Your Path needs to be changed according to your url you posted.
`@Path("{user}")`

Answer (score 0):

Use this `@Path("/{userId}")`. This will work.

URL will like this : `http://localhost:8080/Server_war_exploded/user/{userId}`

Example : `http://localhost:8080/Server_war_exploded/user/1`